# ruby on rails: list records that does not match a given set of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

So, I have three models:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :users, through: :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :restaurants, through: :reviews
end
```

Now, if I want to list all restaurants reviewed by @user I just need:

```
Restaurant.joins(:reviews).where("reviews.user_id": @user.id)
```

Fine. But what if I want to list all restaurants not reviewed by @user? 
I tried this:

```
Restaurant.joins(:reviews).where.not(“reviews.user_id": @user.id)
```

Unfortunately this doesn’t work, as it will also return those restaurants reviewed by @user that have been reviewed by other users!

I came up with this horrible and expensive hack:

```
Restaurant.joins(:reviews).reject {|x| x.users.where(id: @user.id).present? }
```

I’m sure there MUST be a better way. HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy.

You have to map the ids of all restaurants reviewed by @user

```
reviewed_restaurants = Restaurant.joins(:reviews).where("reviews.user_id": @user.id).map(&:id)
```

Then fire another query to fetch restaurants other than those selected before

```
@unreviewed_restaurants = Restaurant.where("id not in (?)", reviewed_restaurants)
```

Hope it works for you.